# React JS How to make some checkboxes checked, based on an array of checked values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newbie to React, and working on a React JS application.  I need to make some checkboxes to be checked default based on a set of values in an array. The domain value set is in another array.

Tried to accomplish the task using a nested loop with `array.map()`
Also, tried to make a callback function within a single loop and tried with array filtering as well. None of them worked correctly:

```
// Set of possible check box values ( file: person.jsx )
Domain=[
     { id:0, name:"apple", value:"Apple" },
     { id:1, name:"orange", value:"Orange"  },
     { id:2, name:"banana", value:"Banana"  },
     { id:3, name:"rGrape", value:"Red grapes"  },
     { id:4, name:"gGrape", value:"Green grapes"  },
]


// a single user's preferences ( file: person.jsx )
state={
    userid:0, 
    name:"Tom",
    gender:"Male",
    age:20,
    fruits:["apple", "rGrape"] 
}
```

The partial code Implemented inside render():

```
// ( file: person.jsx , inside render() )
{ 
this.Domain.map( 
    (fruit, index) => (
        //console.log();
        <p>
            <li key={fruit.id}>  
                <input type="checkbox" 
                    defaultChecked=
                    { //false //if set to false all unchecked
                        this.state.fruits.map(
                            (stateFruit) =>( 
                                 if(fruit.name === stateFruit)
                                        return true;
                                 else
                                        console.log(false);
                                 console.log(fruit.name === stateFruit)
                            )
                        )
                    } 
                    onChange={this.handleChangeChk} /> {fruit.value}
            </li>
        </p>
    )
)
}
```

I expected this only checks user selected fruits but it checks every checkbox. It would be great if anybody could suggest a method to accomplish this task, may be with a different approach.

Comment: The code you've shown doesnt run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to check whether the array of the fruits includes the name:

```
this.state.fruits.includes(fruit.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using javascript `includes` or `contains`

```
{ 
this.Domain.map( 
    (fruit, index) => (
        //console.log();
        <p>
            <li key={fruit.id}>  
                <input type="checkbox" 
                    defaultChecked=
                    { //false //if set to false all unchecked
                        this.state.fruits.includes(fruit.name)
                    } 
                    onChange={this.handleChangeChk} /> {fruit.value}
            </li>
        </p>
    )
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case `map` returns an array of booleans that would always set to `true` you need to use `includes` to return a single boolean value

```
{ 
this.Domain.map( 
    (fruit, index) => (
        //console.log();
        <p>
            <li key={fruit.id}>  
                <input type="checkbox" 
                    defaultChecked=
                    {
                        this.state.fruits.includes(fruit.name)
                    } 
                    onChange={this.handleChangeChk} /> {fruit.value}
            </li>
        </p>
    )
)
}
```

For more details check [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)